# How can I create a Room annotated subclass of a non Room one?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

Given the following initial model, everything seems to work OK with Room:

```
interface ParentModel {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
}

@Entity(tableName = "parents")
open class ParentRoom(
    @PrimaryKey override var name: String,
    override var age: Int)
    : ParentModel
```

However, I don't want to use an interface, I want that to be a *real* class I can make instances of:

```
open class ParentModel(open val name: String, open val age: Int)

@Entity(tableName = "parents")
open class ParentRoom(
    @PrimaryKey override var name: String,
    override var age: Int)
    : ParentModel(name, age)
```

Unfortunately Room won't compile this, because it thinks there are two columns named the same:

```
ParentRoom.java:7: error: Multiple fields have the same columnName: name. Field names: name, name.
public class ParentRoom extends ParentModel {
       ^
e: ParentRoom.java:10: error: Field has non-unique column name.
    private java.lang.String name;
```

The reason I want to override the fields is because that would be the only way to annotate them. Is this possible at all or am I forced to use interfaces with Room?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't need to override fields of parent class. Try with this declaration:

```
open class ParentModel(@PrimaryKey val name: String, val age: Int)

@Entity(tableName = "parents")
class ParentRoom(
    name: String,
    age: Int)
    : ParentModel(name, age)
```

In your declaration, `ParentRoom` has effectively two field with same name. Room processor can not process this situation.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't touch `ParentModel`.

Comment: You have to remove one of the two fields named name: you can do it on ParentRoom or in ParentModel. It's up to you.